# How can I solve this local variable referenced before assignment in below code?

Tags: python, django

```
def Robot_History(Request,id):
    if Request.method == 'POST':
        pi = Robot.objects.get(pk=id)
        fm = list(jenkinsHistory.objects.values('id','robotName','jenkinsBuildNumber','jenkinsBuildStatus','errorMsg','Param').filter(robotName=pi))
        # print("hello",fm)
    rob = Robot.objects.all()
    return render(Request, 'hello/robotHistory.html',{'jenkinsHistory': fm,'robot': rob})
```

That is my code, whenever i try to sun the code i got the error **local variable 'fm' referenced before assignment**
How to solve that ?

Comment: What happens if the request's method _isn't_ POST?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of your code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3890632)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fm` is declared only when `Request.method == 'POST'`

You need to either

- Always assign a value to `fm` (even if `Request.method != 'POST'`)
- Not use `fm` if `Request.method != 'POST'`